# Mimic UICollectionViewFlowLayout in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I would like to create a list of items grouped by sections and where each section can have multiple rows with 2 items by row.

If I use a FlatList, I don't get the section headers, if I use the SectionList I can't succeed to get the items side by side with vertical mode and with horizontal mode obviously the headers are not vertically stacked...

So isn't there a way to mimic the iOS UICollectionViewFlowLayout to display elements like a grid but keeping vertical sections and their headers?